# How to checkout all modified files?

Tags: git, awk

I'm trying to checkout all the modified files from my repo:

```
git status | grep modified | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}'
```

Gives me the files names, i.e. where `git status` returns:

```
modified:    a.txt
modified:    b.txt
```

And awk returns (notice the whitespace):

```
    a.txt
    b.txt
```

I tried replacing the `print` with `git checkout`:

```
git status | grep modified | awk '{split($0,a,":"); git checkout a[2]}'
```

But it didn't work.

I then thought it might be connected to the whitespaces, so I removed them with

```
git status | grep modified | awk '{split($0,a,":"); gsub(" ","",a[2]); git checkout a[2]}'
```

Which, when I used with `print` instead `git checkout`, I saw was printing the file names without any whitespaces, as I wanted.

However, this too didn't work and without any warnings. I thought this might be due to *awk* not invoking the command, just editing the text, so I tried adding a `evil` before, to no avail...

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why not just `git ls-files -mz | xargs -0 git checkout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(I removed `grep` part from your code since `awk` itself could do searching of text) once. I couldn't test it since git is not there in my system :)

```
git status | awk '/modified/{split($0,a,":"); print "git checkout " a[2] > ("script.ksh")} END{close("script.ksh");system("chmod 755 script.ksh;./script.ksh")}'
```

***Explanation:*** In `awk` code simply creating a script file(for those lines only which have string `modified` in them only. Script file name will be script.ksh) with help of `awk` and then executing it by providing proper execute permissions. We could see `man awk` for use of `system` function of `awk` which helps `awk` to run BASH level commands in it's program.One more point `close("script.ksh")` should be DONE to avoid errors like OP got `file is busy....etc` since `awk` program is still running so file will be opened in backend, ater we close it then it could be used for running it.

***EDIT:*** Above solution uses a script file to run all git statements in case you want to run them without creating a file then try following.

```
git status | awk '/modified/{split($0,a,":"); print "git checkout " a[2]}' | sh
```

Comment: I see what you did thre, however this fails on my machine: syntax errors...

Comment: @CIsForCookies, try `git status | awk '/modified/{split($0,a,":"); print "git checkout " a[2] > ("script.ksh")} END{system("chmod 755 script.ksh;./script.ksh")}' `  OR `git status | awk '/modified/{split($0,a,":"); print "git checkout " a[2] > "script.ksh"} END{system("chmod 755 script.ksh;./script.ksh")}'` once and let me know then?

Comment: outputs: Text file busy

Comment: @CIsForCookies, oh sorry, edited my code now, we should `close("script.ksh")` in END section of this code. Check once?

Comment: The temporary file is pretty useless; just pipe to `ksh` directly (or rather, to `sh`, which is what this probably does in spite of the misleading file name).

Comment: @tripleee, yes that was in my mind but few days back while writing code for someone on SO, I got an error where seems std input and std output were busy with code and it was not able to run all statements by `awk .. |  sh` so then I went with this approach, since I have not tested this code so given this approach here.

Comment: @tripleee, I have added `awk ... | sh` solution in post now, thank you for letting know your thoughts here.

Comment: You could still simplify further with `awk -F :`